# Changing src of iFrame is removing the iFrame using jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

Using this jQuery:

```
$('#mycarousel li img').click(function(){
    $('#video').empty();
    var newId = $(this).attr('id');
    newId = newId.replace('vid','');
    $('#video iframe').attr('src', $('.vidHolder' + newId).html());
});
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango"><li><img src="pathtoimage" id="vid1" width="90" height="55" alt="" /></li>

<div id="video"><iframe src="pathtocurrentiframe" style="overflow:hidden"  id="fr"  width="425" height="480" frameborder="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" style="overflow:hidden;"></iframe><div id="dialog" title="" style="width: 0; height: 0;"></div></div>

<div class="vidHolder1" style="display: none;">newpathtoiframe</div>
```

Now for some reason, when i click the img it just removes the iFrame! Not changing the src like i need it to...

Comment: Aren't you clearing out the whole thing with `$('#video').empty();` ? That clears the `iframe` as well if `#video iframe` is a proper selector as `iframe` is then a child of `#video` and will be removed by the `.empty()`

Comment: wow. thanks for this. What a fool!

Comment: Are you putting HTML inside the src attr? What exactly are you trying to change the src to - considering you got the id:1 from the image - what more are you trying to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your problem is the first line of your click function:

```
$('#video').empty();
```

The [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) method removes all child elements, which means it will remove your iframe.

The last line in your function then does nothing because no elements match the selector (but you won't get an error because jQuery is quite happy to do nothing when no elements match the selector).

Comment: Unfortunately, i knew all of this but its very late :( thanks all the same! :)